# Reading deleting SMS from ionic3 / ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In official site, Ionic has introduced SMS (
http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms/)
but the issue is, by this, we can only SEND SMS.
But my use case is to READ, WATCH, DELETE SMS from USER INBOX BOTH in IOS & Android

Any Leads will be appreciated

Comment: I dont think even native apps could be used to do that...Here is Androids permission list https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: for Reading and keep of the watch on SMS traffic is there any solution available?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms plugin to send / list / intercept / delete / restore SMS.

just add plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-sms
```

then you can use any method from following

```
sendSMS(address(s), text, successCallback, failureCallback);
listSMS(filter, successCallback, failureCallback);
deleteSMS(filter, successCallback, failureCallback);
```

for complete docs and example [Go here](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/tree/master/docs)

**Keep in mind that this plugin is not free. do read the full readme.md file**

Comment: I don't have experience in ionic 2 but this are global functions so they would be in window object.
here is a reference [link](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-in-ionic-2-with-ionic-native/) to start with